# replace character string inside button with empty space

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm working on trivia game, the answer consists of characters, each on a button

When I put a space in the answer it doesn't appear as empty space but rather empty button "character"
I tried replacing characters in java file "sceneactivity" so that when the answer consists of two words "space" it directly create a new line with "\n"
but nothing happened, "\n" was considered a character and a part of the possible answer letters

this is what the code looks like

```
        // draw word buttons

    RelativeLayout wordLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wordlayout);
    String[] word = ld.getLevelSpecific().getProcessedWord();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        Button temp = new Button(this);
        word[i] = word[i].replace(" "\\s"\n");
        word[i] = word[i].replaceAll(" ", "\n");

        temp.setText(""); ......................
```

"
 what I want is excluding space, I don't want it to be considered a part of the answer, just empty space or a new line

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code below instead of `\n`:

```
word[i] = word[i].replace(" ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

or this one to remove all whitespaces and non visible characters:

```
word[i] = word[i].replaceAll("\\s","")
```